# Akka HTTP WebSocket Server How to declare Source based on Sink content when building Flow for message handlement?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am playing around with Akka Stream/Http and trying to figure out how to do the following thing in a websocket server (hopefully without using Actor pattern):

1. At initial connection request from client, after the handshake, server will listen to client's initial `Message` in `json` format. 
2. After server received the `TextMessage.Strict` and if valid it will enrich the `Message` to build a "Predicate" (eg. a filter map),   Then the server will use that "Predicate" to build a `Source[Message, _]`. 

I tried using `handleMessagesWithSinkSource` but it seems to me this API's intend is for out-generating `Sink` and `Source` independently(see route `/ws`). I also tried using `handleWebSocketMessages`(see route `ws/filter`), but to me there is no connection between Sink(inlet) and Source(outlet) in the Flow. I must be wrong in understanding how `Sink` should work here:

my route:

```
              (path("ws") & get & pathEndOrSingleSlash) {
                extractUpgradeToWebSocket { upgrade =>
                  complete(upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore,
                    getSourceAll)
                } // this route is working fine, pushing all event Messages to client once connected 
              } ~
              (path("ws" / "filter") & get & pathEndOrSingleSlash) {
                handleWebSocketMessages(getSourceFiltered) 
              } // this route I cannot figure out a way to build `Flow` dynamically based on `Sink`...
```

idea of `getSourceAll` and `getSourceFiltered`

```
val getSourceAll: Source[Message, NotUsed] = ??? // Stream source genereating Messages based on backend event

val getSourceFiltered: Flow[Message, Message, _] = ??? // the outgoing Source should push Server event messages based on client's "Predicate" message
```

After the connection being established, I would expect user send over filter like:

```
{
 productId: 1,
 city: New York
}
```

Then the server should keep pushing data stream(event) in realtime from backend(database) with more detailed product info back to user client:

```
{
orderId: 1122,
productId: 1,
productName: Coke,
vendor: ABC,
city: New York
timestamp: 2019-11-13 09:30:00
}
{
orderId: 3322,
productId: 1,
productName: Coke,
vendor: EFG,
city: New York
timestamp: 2019-11-13 09:31:00
}
...
```

Is `Actor` absolutely required to handle this? if so, any guidance would be really helpful!

**Update**
In short, how can I emit an event-driven server-push Source based on user's Message?
Additionally, maybe I am confused on how to build a new `Source[Message, _]`? I know `Flow` is immutable but should be a way to switch based on input(`Flow.fromSinkAndSource`?). Because Akka only has directive api like: `handleWebSocketMessages(flow: Flow[Message, Message, _])` which only consume the input message, but not produce a new `Source` and as for `handleMessagesWithSinkSource(sink, source)` the sink and source does not have logical connection to me. I am still trying to wrap my head around how to make it work..

Comment: Could you say more about how the predicate is determined in the `"ws" / "filter"` case? Maybe write out a sample of what the user would send over the websocket connection and how the server should reply? Based on what you've written, it seems unlikely you'd need to use `Actor` directly in any way.

Comment: Thank you @Alec I have updated the description with example client-side input and expected server push stream. hope it makes more sense to you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it isn't immediately obvious, `Flow[Message, Message, _]` is enough for implementing most protocols. Remember that a `Flow` can build up almost arbitrary amounts of state via functions like `statefulMapConcat` or `flatMapConcat`. A `Flow` can even start emitting stuff without having directly received an input to reply to via functions like `extrapolate` or `merge`-ing with some ticking source.

In your case:

```
val getSourceFiltered: Flow[Message, Message, _] = Flow[Message]
  .take(1)  // you only care about the first thing that the client sends 
  .flatMapConcat {
    case TextMessage.Strict(txtMsg: String) =>

      // Here is where you parse and make your filter using the message the client message
      val clientFilter: Message => Boolean = makeFilter(txtMsg)
      getSourceAll.filter(clientFilter)


    case _ => Source.single(TextMessage("Expected a single strict JSON message"))
  }
```

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I am looking for. yeah, it's not obvious to me that `Flow[Message, Message, _]` can actually emit `Source` I thought these two `Message` are in/out type and that's it. Thank you @Alec